# Why is my ampscript not populating in an email?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript

So when I am previewing and testing ampscript in an email it is rendering fine, the name shows up. But when I get the email the name field is blank.

```
Hi %%=Propercase(@FirstName)=%%, %%[var @FirstName set @FirstName = [Opportunity:Primary_Contact__r:FirstName]]%%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an order of operations issue, you need to set the VAR before you call it

```
%%[var @FirstName set @FirstName = [Opportunity:Primary_Contact__r:FirstName]]%%

Hi %%=Propercase(@FirstName)=%%,
```

Comment: Okay, sorry I'm brand new to ampscript. Can I just copy and paste the solution you gave me?

Comment: Based on your example code that should be accurate.  You can also simply do a personalization string %%=Propercase(Opportunity:Primary_Contact__r:FirstName)=%%  I would also start with 101 here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/getStarted-AMPscript.htm

Comment: Thank you! This worked.